# Is there a way to generate getters and setters in C# for a sql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a local database and I want to be able to retrieve and insert data into it from C# files.  I have read about the INSERT INTO and SELECT FROM SQL commands, but what I want to do is create C# functions that I can call to insert, edit, and retrieve information from the the database.  For example:

```
public void InsertAccountData(string Usrname, string passwd)
{

    INSERT INTO Account(Username, password) VALUES(Usrname, password);

}
```

I have tried to find an answer, but have not found a solid solution.  How would I do this is C#?

Comment: Are you working with WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF, Console applications, etc?  There are a few different options for you, but specific platform matters.  However, in general, you seem to be asking about ORM - Object/Relational Mapping.  Several ORM tools for .NET exist.  Even plain old Typed Datasets with TableAdapters do pretty much what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void InsertAccountData(string Usrname, string passwd)
{

    string qry = string.format("INSERT INTO Account(Username, password) VALUES('{0}','{1}')", Usrname, password);
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

This is how normally we access the DB. Current example is for MSSQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

Comment: Thank you that helps immensely. The only trouble I have is that when I pass a string, say "duckman1980", I relieve an sql exception stating that 'duckman1980' is not a valid column.  What is causing this?

Comment: @user1082821 - You will need to post the code.  If your getting an invalid column exception then your query code isn't correct.

Comment: @user1082821, see edited answer. '{0}','{1}'. My mistake, i did not notice string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need an Objectmodel, you can write your own as you mentioned in the question or use an existing one like [NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546174.aspx) to map your objects to the database.

Try this too: [Creating the Object Model (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546174.aspx)